Factoring out an element of a root subgroup to make a conjugation integral
Fix a nonarchimedean local field $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$, uniformizer $\varpi$, and residue field $k$. If I take a matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & \varpi b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal{O})$$
then after conjugation by $\begin{pmatrix} \varpi^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & \varpi \end{pmatrix}$, I get
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & \varpi^{-1} b \\ \varpi^2c & d \end{pmatrix}$$
For what I'm doing, it's problematic that there's an exponent of $-1$ before $b$, because this means that the conjugated matrix doesn't necessarily land in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal{O})$ anymore. But I can "fix this" by trying to "factor out the $\varpi^1$-term of $\varpi b$". More precisely, I can find a factorization
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & \varpi b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \varpi[x] \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a' & \varpi^2 b' \\ c' & d' \end{pmatrix}$$
such that $x \in k^\times$ (where $[-]: k^\times \to \mathcal{O}^\times$ is the usual multiplicative section) and such that
$$\begin{pmatrix} a' & \varpi b' \\ c' & d' \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal{O}).$$
Specifically, you get that $x = [b_0]/[d_0]$, where I've written $b = \sum_{n=0}^\infty [b_n]\varpi^n$ and $d = \sum_{n=0}^\infty [d_n]\varpi^n$.
The problem is "fixed" because conjugating $\begin{pmatrix}a' & \varpi^2b' \\ c' & d' \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal{O})$ by $\begin{pmatrix} \varpi^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & \varpi \end{pmatrix}$ lands you in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal{O})$.
Question: is there a better conceptual way of thinking about what I just did? I want to do this for more general groups. In general, $G$ is a split reductive group, and I take a quasi-minuscule (but not minuscule!) cocharacter $\lambda$ (which for $\mathrm{GL}_2$ is the cocharacter $(1,-1)$, hence the conjugation above). I can define a parabolic subgroup $P_\lambda$ of $G(k)$ generated by the roots $\alpha$ of $G$ such that $\langle \alpha, \lambda \rangle \leq 0$.
Then given an element $g \in G(\mathcal{O})$ which reduces to $P_\lambda$ under the reduction map $G(\mathcal{O}) \to G(k)$, I want to factor it as
$$g = N_{\lambda^\vee}(\varpi x) \widetilde{g},$$
where $x \in \mathcal{O} \setminus \varpi \mathcal{O}$ and $\widetilde{g}$ satisfies
$$\varpi^{-\lambda} \widetilde{g} \varpi^\lambda \in G(\mathcal{O}).$$
By $N_{\lambda^\vee}: \mathcal{O} \to G(\mathcal{O})$ I mean the root subgroup for the root $\lambda^\vee$ (it's true that if $\lambda$ is quasi-minuscule, then $\lambda^\vee$ is a root). By $\varpi^\lambda$ I mean $\lambda(\varpi)$.
My thoughts: I want to use the fact that $G$ is generated by root subgroups and the torus, and then take $g$, write it as a product of elements of root subgroups, and then try to factor out the elements appearing in the root subgroup for the root $\lambda^\vee$. But I'm worried because root subgroups don’t necessarily commute with each other, so I fear I can't move these elements all the way to the left.

Did you try to use an Iwahori decomposition ? In the case of GL(2), the element you start with actually lives in the Iwahori subgroup $I$. This Iwahori subgroup has a Iwahori decomposition : $I$=$I\cap U' \cdot I\cap T\cdot I\cap U$, where $B=TU$ is the Borel subgroup and $U'$ is the opposit unipotent. Such Iwahori decompositions exist for more general parahoric subgroups.

Ah thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Elaborating on the comment above. Let $K$ be a local field with ring of integers $O$, and residue field $k$. Let $S \hookrightarrow G(K)$ be a split maximal torus.  The parahoric subgroup $P \hookrightarrow G(O)$, you defined can be described in two ways:

defined as the fiber under the restriction of $G(O)\rightarrow G(k)$, of $P_\lambda(k) \rightarrow G(k)$, where $P_\lambda(k)$ is the subgroup of $G(k)$ generated by opposite  Borel and $(\alpha, \lambda) \le 0$,
As generated by affine functional of apartments, I provide an example for $\operatorname{SL}_2$ below .

In both cases,  we have
$$ (N^+(K) \cap P) \times Z(K)^\circ \times (N^-(K) \cap P) $$
where $N^+(K)$ is the unipotent radical of the minimal parabolic subgroup containing $S$ corresponding to $\Phi^+$.

Then we should understand
$N^+ (K) \cap P$. Note then that in general we have  an explicit isomorphism
$$ 
\prod_{\alpha \in \Phi^{\pm, \text{nd}}} U_{\psi_\alpha} \simeq N^{\pm}(K) \cap P 
$$
over the indecomposable roots, and $\psi_\alpha$ is the smallest affine functional over the apartment of $S$ which has derivative $\alpha$ that is nonnegtive on the chamber that defines $P$.

Let us now do this explicitly in the case of $\operatorname{SL}_2$.

The apartment here is $$A:=X_\bullet \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{R}.$$
The affine roots  $\Phi:=\left \{ a+ j\,:\, a \in \Phi  , j \in Z  \right \}$  are all on the functionals on $A$. Note that the roots here $\Phi =\{ \pm 1 \}$.
For the affine root $\psi:= a+j$, we can introduce a function $U_{\psi}$ defines a root subgroup $U_a(\varpi^j O)$, an embedding $\varpi^j O$ in to the $a$-th root position.


Now  $$N^+(K) \cap P \simeq U_{\psi_{\lambda^\vee}} \cdot \prod_{\Phi^{+,nd} \backslash \lambda^\vee } U_{\psi_\alpha}.$$ I leave it as an exercise to argue that by factoring $U_{\psi_{\lambda^\vee}}$ out in the decomposition the remaining object lives in $P^{\ge \lambda}:= P \cap \varpi^\lambda G(O)\varpi^{-\lambda} $.

footnote: Another (equivalent) definition:  $P=P_x$ the maximal parahoric associated to a point $x \in A$, (the maximal ones are precisely those where $(y,x) \in Z$ for all $y \in \Phi$). It is the subgroup of $G(O)$ generated by $T(O)$ and $U_y(\varpi^{-\lfloor y,x \rfloor})$ for $y \in \Phi$. (The example you given is $x =2 \in A$. )

Thanks, I think this is what I needed!

I think you mean to call $P$ a parahoric, not a parabolic, subgroup.
